# Troubles using `standalone` class with subfig

Tags: floats, standalone, latexmk, crop

I would like to generate a figure which I want to embed in another document as PDF.
For this I would like to use the `standalone` class, which I've used before.
But now I run into great troubles.

The following MWE works as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\imsize}{0.33\linewidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \subfloat[][Here is some text.]{\includegraphics[width=\imsize]{<figure1>}}
    \subfloat[][Here is some more text.]{\includegraphics[width=\imsize]{<figure1>}}
    \subfloat[][Here is even more text, which should then break on several lines.]{\includegraphics[width=\imsize]{<figure1>}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But when I use the `standalone` class to get a minimal figure PDF, the compilation fails, and I cannot seem to find the culprit, e.g. I get `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` when compiling the code below with `latexmk` Version 4.45 on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\imsize}{0.33\linewidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[][Here is some text.]{\includegraphics[width=\imsize]{<figure1>}}
    \subfloat[][Here is some more text.]{\includegraphics[width=\imsize]{<figure1>}}
    \subfloat[][Here is even more text, which should then break on several lines.]{\includegraphics[width=\imsize]{<figure1>}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that figure should be \textwidth or \columnwidth in width,   There are a number of ways to set \textwidth.  I usually use a minipage.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for the hint, I'd prefer not to use a minipage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `preview`  option:

```
\documentclass[preview, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\imsize}{0.32\linewidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[][Here is some text.]{\includegraphics[width=\imsize]{TheLarch}}\enspace
    \subfloat[][Here is some more text.]{\includegraphics[width=\imsize]{TheLarch}}\enspace
    \subfloat[][Here is even more text, which should then break on several lines.]{\includegraphics[width=\imsize]{TheLarch}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]